# How to implement threaded messages in the web-application like facebook

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook

I need to implement threaded messages in my web-application using php and mysql.

Below is my table structure.
[image]

and I am using below query to select thread for logged in user.

Let consider that the logged in user "18" than my query is.

```
SELECT `m1`.`message_id` AS `message_id` , `m1`.`receiver` AS `receiver` , `m1`.`sender` AS `sender` , `m1`.`message` AS `message`, `m1`.`read_status` AS `read_status` , `m1`.`rcvd_date_time` AS `rcvd_date_time` 
FROM (
`messages` `m1` 
LEFT JOIN `messages` `m2` ON ( (
(
`m1`.`receiver` = `m2`.`receiver`
)
AND (
`m1`.`message_id` < `m2`.`message_id`
) )
)
)
WHERE ISNULL( `m2`.`message_id` ) 
AND (
m1.sender =18
OR m1.receiver =18
)
ORDER BY m1.rcvd_date_time DESC
```

And i am getting below result.
[image]

You can see that  i am getting 2 threads for user 25 ,it seems i will get 2 threads for each user using above query.

Can any one help me to implement thtis?

should i need to change the table structure? or query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another column, reply-to-msg-id which tracks which message thread the message is in reply to.

So

```
message_id
in-reply-to-message-id
receiver
sender
```

New threads reply to themselves or 0 or null (depending on how you want to code it)

All other messages replies to message or new threads.

This does not allow nesting, btw.

Comment: Yes so first we need to query using receiver id to whom we wanted to send message if message exist with receiver_id that message_id will be considered as in-reply-message-id (parent_id) if not than message will be entered as a new thread,isn't it?

Comment: If I understand your comment, yes.  If there is no 'in-reply-to-message-id' then it's a new thread. Otherwise, you can recursively grab the related messages into a thread of many levels or restrict the threads to a single level.

Answer (score 0):

The first highlighted message is because you are including the receiver in your query:

```
AND (
m1.sender =18
OR m1.receiver =18
)
```

The second highlighted message has a sender of 18, so that is also included along with the rest of the un-highlighted messages.

Comment: Yes but for first highlight if will not include the sender the messages_threads are not displayed started by logged in user